# Program to compute final grade for weighted assignments

Tags: python, python-3.x

I wrote a "gradebook" program.  This takes in grades for various assignments. The assignments types are weighted differently and final grade is computed at the end.  The code works but I can't help but think I am being ham handed in my approach. Should I be using a dictionary instead of storing things like `hw_final`, `lab_final`, and `exam_final` as global variables?

```
hw_tally = 0
hw_weight_count = 0
hw_final = 0
lab_tally = 0
lab_weight_count = 0
lab_final = 0
exam_tally = 0
exam_weight_count = 0
exam_final = 0


def assignment(kind, grade, weight=1):
    global hw_tally, hw_weight_count, hw_final, lab_tally, lab_weight_count, lab_final, exam_tally, exam_weight_count, exam_final
    if kind == 'hw':
        hw_weight_count += weight
        hw_temporary = (grade * weight)     
        hw_tally += hw_temporary
        hw_final = hw_tally/hw_weight_count
    elif kind == 'lab':
        lab_weight_count += weight
        lab_temporary = (grade * weight)     
        lab_tally += lab_temporary
        lab_final = lab_tally/lab_weight_count
    elif kind == 'exam':
        exam_weight_count += weight
        exam_temporary = (grade * weight)   
        exam_tally += exam_temporary
        exam_final = exam_tally/exam_weight_count


assignment('hw', 81)
assignment('exam', 90, 4)
assignment('hw', 100, 2)
assignment('lab', 84, 3)
assignment('lab', 90, 2)
assignment('exam', 78)
assignment('exam', 85)
assignment('lab', 88)
assignment('exam', 75)

hw_weight_percent = 0.4
lab_weight_percent = 0.1
exam_weight_percent = 0.5

final_grade = ((hw_final * hw_weight_percent) + (lab_final * 
lab_weight_percent) + (exam_final * exam_weight_percent))
print ("Final grade = ", final_grade)
```

Comment: @depperm Comments are for seeking clarification to the question, and may be deleted. Please put all suggestions for in answers, even if they are brief.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it would be better to use a dictionary, that would reduce the amount of global variables. Also you do not need to store and calculated the `..._final` all the times, you can calculate it only when you need need it. The (nested) dictionary to store the grades could be:

```
scores = {
    "hw"   : { "tally" : 0, "weight_count" : 0} ,
    "lab"  : { "tally" : 0, "weight_count" : 0} ,
    "exam" : { "tally" : 0, "weight_count" : 0} ,
}
```

Then the `assignment` function can be made shorter, without calculating the *final* at this moment:

```
def assignment(kind, grade, weight=1):
    global scores
    scores[kind]["weight_count"] += weight
    scores[kind]["tally"] += grade * weight
```

We could write another function to calculate the *final* of a *kind*:

```
def final_of_kind(kind):
    global scores
    return scores[kind]["tally"] / scores[kind]["weight_count"]
```

And the rest of the program is almost the same:

```
assignment('hw', 81)
assignment('exam', 90, 4)
assignment('hw', 100, 2)
assignment('lab', 84, 3)
assignment('lab', 90, 2)
assignment('exam', 78)
assignment('exam', 85)
assignment('lab', 88)
assignment('exam', 75)

hw_weight_percent = 0.4
lab_weight_percent = 0.1
exam_weight_percent = 0.5

final_grade = (  (final_of_kind("hw")   * hw_weight_percent)
               + (final_of_kind("lab")  * lab_weight_percent)
               + (final_of_kind("exam") * exam_weight_percent))

print ("Final grade = ", final_grade)
```

Note: the alignment in the assignment of `final_grade` is frowned up on sometimes, because it is not according to [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), but I use it for readability.

Comment: thanks Jan.  I like your solution more it is easier for me to follow.  The above solution is beyond my level of experience

Answer (score 3):

1. Split `assignment` into three functions. `homework`, `exam` and `labwork`. Take:

   ```
   def homework(grade, weight=1):
       global hw_tally, hw_weight_count, hw_final
       hw_weight_count += weight
       hw_temporary = (grade * weight)     
       hw_tally += hw_temporary
       hw_final = hw_tally/hw_weight_count
   ```
2. Change `homework` into a class.

   ```
   class Scores:
       def __init__(self):
           self.tally = 0
           self.weight_count = 0

       @property
       def final(self):
           return self.tally / self.weight_count

       def grade(grade, weight=1):
           self.weight_count += weight
           self.tally += grade * weight
   ```

   Now you can use the above class to total all the separate things. And then perform your total on `Scores.final`.
3. Group the exam types into another class, say `StudentScores`.
4. Expand `Scores` to also take the percentage. And make `final` return the percentage.
5. Move your final calculation into `StudentScores`.

This can make:

```
class Scores:
    def __init__(self, percentage=1):
        self.tally = 0
        self.weight_count = 0
        self.percentage = percentage

    @property
    def final(self):
        return self.tally / self.weight_count * self.percentage

    def grade(self, grade, weight=1):
        self.weight_count += weight
        self.tally += grade * weight


class StudentScores:
    def __init__(self, scores):
        total = sum(scores.values())
        self._scores = {
            key: Scores(score / total)
            for key, score in scores.items()
        }

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        return self._scores[name]

    @property
    def grade(self):
        return sum(scores.final for scores in self._scores.values())


student = StudentScores({
    'homework': 0.4,
    'labwork': 0.1,
    'exam': 0.5
})

student.homework.grade(81)
student.exam.grade(90, 4)
student.homework.grade(100, 2)
student.labwork.grade(84, 3)
student.labwork.grade(90, 2)
student.exam.grade(78)
student.exam.grade(85)
student.labwork.grade(88)
student.exam.grade(75)

print("Final grade = ", student.grade)
```

---

This uses a lot of classes, and isn't really the best way if you're taking data from a file. And so if you store your results as a JSON file, and read it into Python however you want. Then you can default the weights into the JSON data. And then perform the rest of the code in a couple of comprehensions, wrapped in a `sum`:

```
results = {
    'homework': [
        0.4,
        [
            [81],
            [100, 2]
        ]
    ],
    'labwork': [
        0.1,
        [
            [84, 3],
            [90, 2],
            [88]
        ]
    ],
    'exam': [
        0.5,
        [
            [90, 4],
            [78],
            [85],
            [75]
        ]
    ]
}

def default_weights(results):
    return [
        [percentage, [(score + [1])[:2] for score in scores]]
        for percentage, scores in results.values()
    ]

def grade(results):
    return sum(
        percentage * sum(s*w for s, w in scores) / sum(w for _, w in scores)
        for percentage, scores in results
    )

print("Final grade = ", grade(default_weights(results)))
```